# Google Cloud Function error [ReferenceError: publishMessage is not defined]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

So I'm working on a Google Cloud function to upload data to FireStore Firebase.

Followed this video step by step

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ON_3hfPOuyI&t=9m31s

But I can an error message [ReferenceError: publishMessage is not defined]

My Google Cloud is linked to my FireStore

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp ({
 credentials: admin.credential.applicationDefault()
});

var db = admin.firestore();

exports.helloPubSub = (event, context) => {

const pubsubMessage = event;

var dataToFirestore = Buffer.from
(pubsubMessage.data, 'base64').toString();
var serialnumber = pubsubMessage.attributes.device_id;
var publishTime = publishMessage.attributes.published_at;

var docRef = db.collection('TestDataUseage').add({Test: "Wish",Test2: "I hope this 
works"});


var docRef2 = db.collection('TestDataUseage').add({ToFireStore: dataToFirestore});
callback();


};
```

Really new to Google Cloud functions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `publishMessage` was never instantiated, at least on the block of code you shared.

Try changing the line to the following:

```
// old value -> var publishTime = publishMessage.attributes.published_at;
var publishTime = pubsubMessage.attributes.published_at;
```

as it will call to pubsubMessage which is what you called on the line directly above this one.

Hope this helped you.